# How to stop one eventListener when start another on the same element?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating some kind of gallery in js as a practice. I found an error and I don't know how to solve it.

**Full code of on JSFiddle** -> 
    [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/feamor/5darpeby/)

**Background**

I add two eventListeners to my img wrapper, 
wrapper looks like that:

```
<div class="gallery-item"> <-- wrapper
 <img src=""> <-- image
 <div> <-- overlay
 </div>
</div>
```

and listeners like that (listeners I'm adding during creating wrappers in js):

```
imageWrapper.addEventListener('mouseenter', enableOverlay, false);
imageWrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', disableOverlay, false);
```

Listeners invokes functions, which are responsible for displaying overlay over image. First of them show overlay with fade effect and the second one hide it with the same effect.

*enableOverlay*

```
function enableOverlay(e) {
    var el = this.childNodes[1].style;
    el.display = 'block';
    (function fadeIn() {
        if (el.opacity < 1) {
            el.opacity = parseFloat(el.opacity) + Number(0.1);
            setTimeout(fadeIn, 30);
        }
    }());
}
```

*disableOverlay*

```
function disableOverlay(e) {
    var el = this.childNodes[1].style;
    (function fadeOut() {
        if (el.opacity > 0) {
            el.opacity = parseFloat(el.opacity) - Number(0.1);
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 30);
        } else {
            el.display = 'none';
        }
    }());
}
```

**Problem**

On first sight everything is ok if I'm slowly move mouse over images - one function ends (opacity = 1) and the second is starting until opacity = 0. But when I'm moving mouse fast over images, overlays start to blink - opacity increases and decreases by 0.1 (value in IIFEs) and script loop.

As I figured out, reason of this behavior is that *enableOverlay* dosen't finish (el.opacity dosen't reach 1) and in the same time *disableOverlay* starts. And I don't know how to fix this situation.

I was trying to deal with it using flags which represents the state of fading function and breaks IFFEs, but it didn't help.

Long story short, can anyone help me with this problem or show me a way of thinking to solve it?

**EDIT**

In my opinion, my problem is 'how to stop function in one eventListener when another eventListeners is fired'. Changing opacity is only a sample.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're not using css transforms for your opacity changes?

Comment: i know i can use css, but in this one i want to use js, because this code is some kind of practice for me. if i don't figure out how to do this in proper way in js i'll use css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added an attribute to track the event.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwhzqk3a/11/)

```
function disableOverlay(e) {
    var el = this.childNodes[1].style;
    var that = this.childNodes[1];
   that.setAttribute('op','fadeOut');
    (function fadeOut() {
        if (el.opacity > 0 && that.getAttribute('op')==='fadeOut') {
            el.opacity = parseFloat(el.opacity) - Number(0.1);
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 30);
        } else {
            el.display = 'none';
        }
    }());
}
```

Comment: thank you, if think it is the easiest way in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can use css transition.

```js
function enableOverlay(e) {
    var el = this.childNodes[1].style;
    el.opacity = '1';
}

function disableOverlay(e) {
    var el = this.childNodes[1].style;
    el.opacity = '0';
}
```

```css
.gallery-item img+div {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjqpxzmj/

Comment: i want to use js, because this is my goal and this is for me good experience. I think the problem isn't this case (how to change opacity) but how to stop function in one eventlistener when another eventlistener starts

Comment: How about use setInterval on both eventListeners and clear it in one, if another starts?

Comment: could you tel me more about this or show me some snippset? because i don't know exactly whats on your mind with interavls

Answer (score 0):

In your case, catching the latest setTimeout and calling clearTimeout on it from the other function should help.

Comment: thank you, it's helps! now everything works ok. i'm catching setTimeout from enableOverlays fadeIn function and clearTimeout in disableOverlay, because i want to fade out overlay every time.